# AngularJS $resource error - TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'

Tags: angularjs

I have the following in my controller file:

```
var Subject = $resource('/api/TestAccounts/:action', { applicationId: 3 }, {
   'getSelect': { method: 'GET', params: { action: 'GetSelect' } }
});

Subject.getSelect({ applicationId: 3 },
   function (resp) {
      $scope.testAccounts = resp;
      gridData = null;
   }
);
```

My server code runs and returns:

```
[{"id":5,"name":"xxx"},{"id":6,"name":"yyy"}]
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'
    at copy (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/angular.js:577:21)
```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just changed `MyService.get(...)` to `MyService.query(...)` because `.get()` expects an object and `.query()` expects an array.

Answer (score 49):

You need to set the paramater `isArray` to true in your resource definition if you are returning an array from the server.

```
var Subject = $resource('/api/TestAccounts/:action', { applicationId: 3 }, {
  'getSelect': { method: 'GET', isArray: true, params: { action: 'GetSelect' } }
});
```

See: [AngularJS $resource API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource)

Comment: that's a pretty unintelligible exception message, for a mistake that can be made so easily. Still, this is definitely the answer

Comment: Yeah some of the error messages in Angular are a bit vague. They have gotten better, however this one still is a major pain for those still learning the ropes.

Comment: Had the same issue and changed output to JSON. Seemed like a better option if you have that luxury.

Answer (score 7):

By default, GET expects an object {}, QUERY expects an array[]. In your case, Web API returns an array for GET, so you need to set isArray flag for GET as true. If your Web API returned an object, then you would not need to reset that flag because it is GET's default behavior.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is a bit stale but I found a solution when I ran into this problem today. Following the post below, I implemented joelwreed's solution (half way down the thread).  It does a check that the destination is an array before trying to push, which fixes the issue.

[Link to issue filed on github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1044)