# AngularJS Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'

Tags: angularjs

Can someone help me unravel this mystery.

My first $resource return a list.
Then, i loop through the list and call another $resource for each object in the collection.
This code was working using $http, but I was told i should be using the $resource for restful and there u go, I am stuck.

I am getting error : AngularJS Object # has no method 'push'

My restful service returns a JSON object:

In my service/factory :

```
services.factory('XXXXFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/xxxx-webapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/restful/services/XXXOption/actions/listAll/invoke', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true },
        create: { method: 'POST' }
    })
});
```

In my controller :

```
app.controller('XXXXListCtrl', ['$scope', 'XXXXsFactory', 'XXXXXFactory', '$location',
      function ($scope, XXXXsFactory, XXXXXFactory, $location) {

    XXXXsFactory.query(function(data) {
        // success handler
          var resultType = data.resulttype;
          var objects = data.result.value;
          $scope.rowList= [];
          console.log(objects);

          alert('list? = '+ resultType);

          if(resultType == "list"){   

            angular.forEach(objects, function (item) {

                alert('item href = '+ item.href);

                var InnerXXXXResource = $resource(item.href, {}, { query: { method: 'GET', isArray: true}});     
                InnerXXXXResource .query(function(rowdata) {
                     $scope.rowList.push(rowdata);  

                    }, function(error) { });    
            });
          }

        }, function(error) {
            // error handler
        });

    }]);
```

HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowList">
        <td width="70%">{{row.members.XXXDescription.value}}</td>
        <td align ="center" width="30%">{{row.members.price.value}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: If you add isArray:true to a resource, the return data from backend should be an array (not a JSON object)

Comment: Is this the actual code that's giving the error?  I can't find anything wrong trying to `push` to an array.

Comment: Thanks Vincent .. Pls, How do I make the return type a JSON Object?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ;)

Is it possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932422/angularjs-resource-error-typeerror-object-g-has-no-method-push?

Comment: Which line threw this error?

Comment: Funny enough when I commented out the line $scope.rowList.push(rowdata);                                         I was still getting the error. The error was pointing at at copy (http://localhost:8080/angularjscrud/lib/angular/angular.js:593:21)
    at new Resource (http://localhost:8080/angularjscrud/lib/angular/angular-resource.js:350:9)

Comment: Pls, How do I make the return type a JSON Object?

Comment: @olatom `res.jsonp(foo);` is how I do it.  ;)

Comment: Sorry I am very new to angularjs ... Where do I fit that in my code?

Comment: I am getting another error. Please, see my new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172921/angularjs-typeerror-number-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post data to server and client:

So, in your controller you should get the data using your Factory

`$scope.data = XXXXFactory.query();`

And if you are dealing with objects change `isArray: false`

and Posting the data to sever

```
$scope.createInventory = function(){
        XXXXFactory.create($scope.newdata); // posts data to server side
        $scope.data.objects.push($scope.newdata); //posts data to client side
        $scope.newdata = '';
};
```